# How to include the scoped model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, include

Let we have the following models:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mandatory_fields, class_name: "TaskField", foreign_key: :task_id      
end

class TaskField < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :service_field

  scope :by_name, (->(name) {
   joins(:service_field).merge(ServiceField.by_name(name))
  })
end

class ServiceField < ApplicationRecord
  #with name column
  scope :by_name, ->(name) {
    where(name: name.to_sym )
  }
end
```

Then let I would like to see the on the page the concrete `:mandatory_fields` for each task:

```
Task.includes(:mandatory_fields).limit(10).map{|t| t.mandatory_fields.by_name(:check_in_confirmed)}
```

As result I have the N+1, when each TaskField calls the ServiceField. Is there way to avoid N+1 there?

UPD: to resolve the issue, I have used the `select`, but maybe exists better solution?

```
Task.includes(:mandatory_fields => :service_field).limit(10).map{|t| t.mandatory_fields.select{|mf| mf.service_field.name == 'check_in_confirmed'}}
```

Comment: What about using AR select and where? `Task.includes(:mandatory_fields => :service_field).select('service_field.name').where(service_field: { name: 'check_in_confirmed' }).limit(10)`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, thanks. But this does not solve the task globally. I need not only `service_filed.name` on my view but almost all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to the following:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mandatory_fields, class_name: "TaskField", foreign_key: :task_id      
  has_many :service_fields, through: :mandatory_fields ## <-- Add this line
end

Task.includes(:service_fields).map do |task|  
  task.service_fields.by_name(:check_in_confirmed)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working technic in general. For my case I need to loop through `mandatory_fields`(not `service_fields`) which should be selected by related `service_field`.